# Return an arraylist without passing an argument

Tags: java, recursion

```
static ArrayList<Integer> LinearSearch(int[] arr,int index,int target) {
        ArrayList<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(index == arr.length){
            return iList;
        }
        if(arr[index] == target){
            iList.add(index);
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = LinearSearch(arr,index+1,target);
        iList.addAll(temp);
        return iList;
    }
```

Above code is my instructors code. I don't understand the `temp` part. How the indexes are adding to `temp`? example `arr = 1,2,3,4,3`: it should return `4,2` but it returns `2,4`.

How is this possible? I can't understand. What is going on with the stack? Please help me to understand.

Below is my own code, which I understand. Here we collect items. But I can't understand the above code.

```
static ArrayList<Integer> LinearSearch(int[] arr,int index,int target) {
        ArrayList<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(index == arr.length){
            return iList;
        }
        iList = LinearSearch(arr,index+1,target);
        if(arr[index] == target){
            iList.addFirst(index);
        }
        return iList;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question title. With that title, I would expect to see something like `ArrayList<Integer> foo () { ... }` -- A method with `ArrayList<Integer>` return type, and an empty parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand the `temp` part. How the indexes are adding to `temp`? example `arr = 1,2,3,4,3`: it should return `4,2` but it returns `2,4`.

`temp` captures the array list that the recursive call returns: it contains the matching indices, but only from the given index (`index+1`) onward. With `addAll` all these matching indices are appended to (after!) the content we already have. The content we already have is either an empty list, or (if the current index has a match) it has one element, which is `index`. As `addAll` adds indices *after* that first element, and those additional indices are guaranteed to be at least `index+1` (as the recursive call only looks from that index onward), we can be certain that `iList` will have the indices in *increasing* order.

Notice where your code is different. In essence you *first* make the recursive calls and collect the indices it returns, and only *then* you check whether the current index `index` has a matching value, and add it *before* those if it matches (not *after*). But the result is the same as with the instructor's code because these two changes cancel eachother out:

```
1. Adding the recursive results first instead of last, 
2. Adding the `index` *before* instead of *after* what you already have.
```

If we were to take your instructor's code and just change the order of adding the recursive results with the (optional) adding of the `index`...:

```
    static ArrayList<Integer> LinearSearch(int[] arr,int index,int target) {
        ArrayList<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(index == arr.length){
            return iList;
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = LinearSearch(arr,index+1,target);
        iList.addAll(temp);
        // Moved the addition of the current index AFTER 
        //    the recursive results were added:
        if(arr[index] == target){
            iList.add(index);
        }
        return iList;
    }
```

...then the result for the example input will be `4,2`. Notice that here we have `iList.add(index)` and not `iList.addFirst(index)`, and so the order is reversed to `4,2`.